Change Textfield placeholder color in SwiftUI on macOS
I am trying to set the placeholder color of a Textfield on macOS. I tried:
TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("prompt"))
                    .tint(.red)

but that does not seem to get respected.
.accentColor is deprecated (and doesn't work), .foregroundStyle does not affect it  (no matter if I put it outside the texfield or directly on the prompt), .colorMultiply is not correct as it applies to the entire field and it's a blending mode, not a setting of an individual color (it makes everything the color you set it to).
I tried to do a custom styling by subclassing TextFieldStyle but couldn't find any modifier that would affect it.
Do I need to resort to a custom NSViewRepresentable and AppKit? I thought SwiftUI would support these features by now. Maybe I'm missing something.
I also have the same problem with the caret color.

You could always show the prompt as an overlay. Then you can style it any way you like:
TextField("", text: $text)
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        if text.isEmpty {
            Text("prompt")
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .padding(.leading, 4)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
    }

The caret adopts the color defined as AccentColor in the asset catalog. But of course, this is used in a lot of other places too.

Thanks you so much Benzy! It never occurred to me to do this as an overlay. Clever! As for the caret color -> you're right, it changed when I set the AccentColor. In the docs I found this section 'By default, your accent color applies to all views and controls in your app that use a tint color, unless you override the color for a specific subset of the view hierarchy.' How would I go about overriding it? The .tint() modifier is not obeyed. Even though the docs say You can set the tint color with the tint() modifier. If no explicit tint is set, the tint is derived from the app’s accent color.

@VojtaBöhm I think .tint is supposed to be the way to override the accent color. The documentation says Use this method to override the default accent color for this view. But as you say, it doesn't seem to work very reliably. The note at the bottom of the same documentation page describes other cases where MacOS ignores the tint color. Ps. thanks for the upvote!

Didn't notice that note, thanks! At least the docs say that the tint is not always respected. I might file a radar. And you're welcome. I love to see what SO has become. So many helpful, knowledgable people :)
